# Get latest Document with respect to (time or Id) using Pymongo only

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, pymongo-2.x

In MongoDB, this technique is commonly used to obtain the latest document with respect to (time or ID):

```
 db.collection.find().sort({ "_id": -1 }).limit(1);

 MySchema.find().sort({ _id: -1 }).limit(1)

db.getLastInsertedDocument.find({}).sort({_id:-1}).limit(1);
```

But when I use pymongo to find the latest entry in my collection the code below gives an error.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

import random
import datetime
import time
import pprint
from datetime import datetime
#from bson import ObjectId

client = MongoClient()
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client.sensor_temperature # createdb
posts = db.posts2
print('Total Record for the collection: ' + str(posts.count()))

x=datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")

record=posts.find().sort({ "_id": -1 }).limit(1)  ###  ERR
#record=posts.find({"start_date":new Date()}).pretty() ####  ERR
#record=posts.findOne({"_id": x}) #### <pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x0141FCD0>
pprint.pprint(record)
text=record
print(text)
```

How to get the latest records using Pymongo only?

Answer (score 0):

Some of the pymongo driver commands don't match exactly to the mongodb shell. [The documentation](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.sort) explains the method calls. This should work:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient, DESCENDING
<...>
record=posts.find().sort('_id', DESCENDING).limit(1)
pprint.pprint(list(record)[0])
```